# For Each does not loop through sheets (without error)

Tags: excel, vba

I need quick help to find my mistake.

The code below should loop through sheets and copy data to respective columns.
But it only copies from 1 sheet
I tried reseting varaiables but nothing helps..

I have similar macro where For each loop and the same If statement works with out problem.

Update:

It appears the problem is here no matter what kind of outer loop i write to jump to next row it does not jump, It just keeps overwriting cells..

```
For Each c In MyDataHeaders 
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(c.value, ColHeaders, 0) 'Finds the 
matching column name Rng.Offset(, i - 1).value = Intersect(DataBlock.EntireRow, 
c.EntireColumn).value 'Writes the values 
Stop 
Next c
```

Code below:

```
 Sub CopyDataBlocks()

 Dim sht As Worksheet
 Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet    'The data to be copied is here
 Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet    'The data will be copied here
 Dim ColHeaders As Range         'Column headers on Target sheet
 Dim MyDataHeaders As Range      'Column headers on Source sheet
 Dim DataBlock As Range          'A single column of data
 Dim c As Range                  'a single cell
 Dim Rng As Range                'The data will be copied here (="Place holder" for the first data cell)
 Dim i As Integer

 'Change the names to match your sheetnames:
'Set SourceSheet = Sheets("ws1")
Set TargetSheet = Sheets("Master")

With TargetSheet
Set ColHeaders = .Rows(1) '.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) 'Or just .Range("A1:C1")
Set Rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'Shoots up from the bottom of the sheet untill it bumps into something and steps one down

End With

For Each SourceSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If SourceSheet.name Like "Sheet*" Then

With SourceSheet
Set MyDataHeaders = Intersect(.Rows(1), .UsedRange)


 For Each c In MyDataHeaders
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ColHeaders, c.value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't find a matching header name for " & c.value & vbNewLine & "Make sure the column names are the same and try again."
        Exit Sub
    End If
 Next c

'There was a match for each colum name.
'Set the first datablock to be copied:
    Set DataBlock = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'A2:A & the last cell with something on it on column A

'Resizes the target Rng to match the size of the datablock:
Set Rng = Rng.Resize(DataBlock.Rows.Count, 1)

'Copies the data one column at a time:
For Each c In MyDataHeaders
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(c.value, ColHeaders, 0) 'Finds the matching column name
    Rng.Offset(, i - 1).value = Intersect(DataBlock.EntireRow, c.EntireColumn).value    'Writes the values
Next c

End With

Set MyDataHeaders = Nothing
End If
Next SourceSheet

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have other sheets that start with word `Sheet`?  This line: `SourceSheet.name Like "Sheet*" ` insures that only sheets starting with `Sheet` make it through.

Comment: Minor point: most VBA programmers would replace `Dim i As Integer` by `Dim i As Long`. With modern versions of Excel (with more than 32,000 or so rows) `Integer` risks overflow for no real gain.

Comment: Yes, multiple Sheet1, Sheet2, ..., Sheet40

Comment: With Stop I narrowed down to this part:

    `For Each c In MyDataHeaders
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(c.value, ColHeaders, 0) 
   'Finds the matching column name
        Rng.Offset(, i - 1).value = Intersect(DataBlock.EntireRow, 
    c.EntireColumn).value    'Writes the values
        Stop
    Next c`

It owerwrite each sheets values and does not jump to next row I reckon I need to put counter and jump to next row.. silly me